FrankenPHP crashes on high loads
FrankenPHP crashes on high loads
FrankenPHP in a VM ,10G Vram ,40G VHD,crashes.
The problem is that it  Crashed will automatically exit, Need to set up automatic restart.and the same happens when you switch to the latest official version 1.2.5. That is:
wget   https://github.com/dunglas/frankenphp/releases/download/v1.2.5/frankenphp-linux-x86_64
sudo chmod 777  ./frankenphp-linux-x86_64
sudo ./frankenphp-linux-x86_64   run --config caddyfile

     free_mem=800001
      while [ $free_mem -gt 800000 ]
         do 
         free_mem=cat /proc/meminfo | grep '^MemAvailable' | awk '{ print $2 }'
         echo " Free_mem:"$free_mem
         while [ $free_mem -lt 800000 ]
           do break 3
         done
         ./frankenphp-linux-x86_64 run  --config caddyfile
      done

crashes
SSH Unable to connect.
reboot OK
We ported from ATS to FrankenPHP, the PHP source code remains the same, and we use the same basic techniques for PHP proxies and online programs such as :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHProxy
https://github.com/PHProxy/phproxy
Exemple de site web pour la candidature :
http://adaiu.dns.navy/1
Since the PHP program is raw code, it is not compiled, and the library used by the PHP environment is not known, and the PHP programmer does not care. Just like writing a web page in Notepad, you don't have to worry about the technology used by the web server. Testing for compatibility with the proxy project mentioned above might also solve this problem.
Dockerfile for shenzhou-app's static-build.
FROM dunglas/frankenphp:static-builder
# Copy your app
WORKDIR /go/src/app/dist/app
COPY . .
# Build the static binary
WORKDIR /go/src/app/dist/app
RUN rm -r dist/static-php-cli/watcher
RUN EMBED=dist/app/ . /build-static.sh
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)

caddyfile ：
 {
    frankenphp
    order php_server before file_server
}

# Website root directory (adjust path as needed)
:80 {
    # Enable compression
    encode zstd br gzip

    # PHP program location, here please modify according to the actual root directory
    root * /tmp/frankenphp_1b73543cc848c8af8018b0cb0a54feee/public/

    # Return to empty page
    @blank path_regexp blank ^//blank/|^/blank/|^/favicon\.ico$
    route @blank {
        header Access-Control-Allow-Origin “*”
        header Cache-Control “public, max-age=31536000”
        respond “” 200
        abort
    }

    # Access the resource cache file directly
    @f1 path_regexp f1 ^/files/(\w)(\w\w)(\w{13})-\w-[\w\-]+(\. \w{2,4})$
    route @f1 {
        rewrite /temp/{http.regexp.f1.1}/{http.regexp.f1.2}/{http.regexp.f1.1}{http.regexp.f1.2}{http.regexp.f1.3}{http.regexp.f1.4}
    }
    @f2 path_regexp f2 ^/files/\w/\w{10}(\w)(\w\w)(\w{13})\w{6}/[\w/]+(\. \w{2,4})$
    route @f2 {
        rewrite /temp/{http.regexp.f2.1}/{http.regexp.f2.2}/{http.regexp.f2.1}{http.regexp.f2.2}{http.regexp.f2.3}{http.regexp.f2.4}
    }
    @tempfiles {
        path_regexp tempfiles {
        path_regexp tempfiles ^/temp/\w/\w\w/\w{16}\. \w{2,4}$
    }
    route @tempfiles {
        # Don't process any content, pass directly to static file
        file_server
        abort
    }

    # If no matching file or directory is found, pass to unified entry
    @notFound {
        not file
    }
    route @notFound {
        rewrite /index.php?__nonematch__=1
    }

    # Forbidden directories or files
    @forbidden {
        __nonematch__=1 } # Forbidden directories or files @forbidden {
        not {
            path /robots.txt
        }
        path_regexp forbidden ^/(data|include|temp|plugin)/|\.db$|\.htaccess$|~\w+$|\\.bak$|\.inc$|\\.sh$\\\\.yaml$|\.ini$|\.bat$|\.dat$\\\\.txt$| \.lock$|\.conf$|\.inc\.php$|^/images/enc\.js$
    }
    respond @forbidden “” 404

    # PHP server
    php_server
}

